# Переписать одномерный массив в двумерный

Tags: java, массивы

Есть определённый класс, внутри которого есть метод, заполняющий данные в одномерный массив. Вопрос: как записать этот массив в строку другого двумерного массива?
Пытался сделать через метод System.arrayCopy, но не могу понять, как это оформить.

Comment: А размер одномерного массива совпадает с размером строки у двумерного?

Comment: Да. Размер одноменого массива всегда 5 , и размер строки двумерного тоже всегда 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вот такой вариант, при условии что размер одномерного массива совпадает( или меньше ) с размером строки у двумерного :

```
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr1[] = {11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91};
        int arr2[][] = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
        for(int a: arr1) System.out.print(a + " ");
        System.out.println("-----------------");
        System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, arr2[0], 0, arr1.length);
        for(int[] a: arr2) for(int b: a) System.out.print(b + " "); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Что тут придумывать то?
Тем более пока учишься нужно ручками писать, а не arraycopy'ть.
В цикле пиши и все.

```
public class Main { 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr1[] = new int [5];
    //массив только еще заполнить не забудь чем-нибудь, а то NPE схватишь
    int arr2[][] = new int [5][5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++){
        arr2[0][i] = arr1[i];
    }
}
```

}